# DataTable in R Shiny with SearchPane Vertically Stacked next to DataTable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I created a DT DataTable with searchPane in an R Shiny app, and would like to have the searchPane boxes stacked vertically next to the DataTable, instead at the top.

I found that it is described in here:
https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/customisation/verticalPanes.html
But would be interested in an implementation in R, but it appears that it is not supported in the current implementation of DT.

A small implementation using the example from R DataTables https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  DT::DTOutput("example")
))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server = function(input, output, session) {
  

output$example <- DT::renderDT(
  datatable(
    iris,
    options = list(dom = 'Pfrtip', columnDefs = list(list(
      searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = 1:4
    ))),
    extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
    selection = 'none'
  )
 )   
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

I tried to use the DOM described in https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/customisation/verticalPanes.html, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces the desired layout, but I don't know why the search panes are empty.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- "
div.dtsp-verticalContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.dtsp-verticalPanes,
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.container{
    width: 30%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.dtsp-verticalPanes{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 26%;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalPanes {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
 
div.dtsp-title {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 13px !important;
}
 
input.dtsp-search {
    min-width: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.dtsp-verticalPanes div.dtsp-searchPanes{
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 0px;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.dtsp-verticalPanes div.dtsp-searchPanes div.dtsp-searchPane{
    flex-basis: 0px;
}
 
div.dtsp-verticalContainer div.container{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 60%;
}
 
div.dtsp-panesContainer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
}
"

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  tags$div(
    class = "dtsp-verticalContainer",
    tags$div(class = "dtsp-verticalPanes"),
    tags$div(
      class = "container",
      DT::DTOutput("example")
    )
  )
)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$example <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        dom = '<"dtsp-dataTable"frtip>',
        searchPanes = list(layout = "columns-1")
      ),
      extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
      selection = 'none',
      callback = JS(
        "table.searchPanes();",
        "$('div.dtsp-verticalPanes').append(table.searchPanes.container());"
      )
    )
  )   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It does work for the example, but I am having some troubles adding this to my app (maybe it's because it is inside a module?). I will try to narrow down the problem in my implementation and open a new question in case I'm unable to solve it.